# Word2013 VBA disable spellchecking does not update screen

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word macro, orginally recorded by performing the actions with user interface:

```
    Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = False
    Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = False
    ActiveDocument.ShowGrammaticalErrors = False
    ActiveDocument.ShowSpellingErrors = False
```

However , after executing the commands, Word keeps showing spell check errors. When disabled from user interface, the dissappear. Am I missing some kind of Refresh command ?

Comment: According to some trial and tests you need to either wait or change selection in your document by mouse to trigger it.

Comment: Hmm, selection change did not do the trick, however switch to preview mode and back seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these codes, Document will get refreshed.

```
ActiveDocument.Application.ScreenRefresh

ActiveDocument.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```